# Android: Set Width of PopupMenu to Match Parent

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, popupmenu

I am trying to implement a custom drop down menu using **PopupMenu**.

I have set a null key listener to the edit text and onclick of the edit text the PopupMenu appears. I have used the following code to implement PopupMenu.

```
mStatusEt.setKeyListener(null);


@OnClick(R.id.newProsStatusEt)
public void onMStatusEtClicked() {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(AddProspectActivity.this, mStatusEt);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.status_popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            mStatusEt.setText(item.getTitle());
            return true;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

Everything is working fine but the width of PopupMenu doesn't match the width of its parent.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.!

[image]

Comment: I think there are some limitations to tweak the PopupMenu in Android. You can achieve your requirement successfully with a PopupWindow however.

Comment: It is not possible to do in straighforward way. Maybe using reflection will do the trick.

Comment: @azizbekian I have no idea of reflection. Any guides, tutorials, docs or links?

Comment: I investigated the code, and couldn't find enough seams to do that via [reflection](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/java-reflection-tutorial/) also. You have to handle it customly.

Comment: @azizbekian thanks.! for the help